# Post a list and iterate it using Dart

Tags: json, mongodb, dart

I'm trying to post some data from a dart project to another and store them in a mongoDB

Post code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

    List example = [
        {"source": "today", "target": "tomorrow"},
        {"source": "yesterday", "target": "tomorrow"},
        {"source": "today", "target": "yesterday"}     
    ];

    new HttpClient().post('localhost', 4040, '')
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
            request.headers.contentType = ContentType.JSON;
            request.write(example);
            return request.close();
    });
}
```

Code that receives it, inside another file

```
void start() {    
    HttpServer.bind(address, port)
        .then((HttpServer server) {
            // Log in console to show that server is listening
            print('Server listening on ${address}:${server.port}');
            server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
                request.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen(sendToDatastore);
        });        
    });
}

void sendToDatastore(String contents) {
    var dbproxy = new dbProxy("myDb");
    dbproxy.write("rawdata", contents);
    index++;

    // non related to the problem code
}

bool write(collectionName, document)
{
    Db connection = connect();        
    DbCollection collection = connection.collection(collectionName);

    connection.open().then((_){
        print('writing $document to db');
        collection.insert(document);
    }).then((_) {
        print('closing db');
        connection.close();
    });        
    return true;        
}
```

What I'm struggling with is that I'm using

```
request.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen(sendToDatastore);
```

so I'm converting the request stream to a string as I couldn't find the way to send it as Json.

And then in sendToDatastore I'm not able to parse it properly in order to store it. As far as I understand I'd need to get every Json object as a Map to store it as I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'document'.
```

Thanks,

UPDATE

If I try to do something like this in sendToDatastore

```
    void sendToDatastore(String contents) {
    var dbproxy = new dbProxy("myDb");
    var contentToPass = JSON.decode(contents);
    contentToPass.forEach((element) => dbproxy.write("rawdata", element));
    index++;

    // non related to the problem code
}
```

It raises this error

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)
[{source: today, target: tomorrow}, {source: yesterday, target: tomorrow}, ...
  ^
```

In the use of JSON.decode

UPDATE2

The error was that I wasn't sending actual Json from the "post code". I used

```
// ...
request.write(JSON.encode(example));
// ...
```

and everything worked fine

Thanks

Comment: I don't see you using `JSON.encode`. Also where does `rates`  come from in the server side? You could just use `JSON.encode(example)` instead of `rates` when writing to the stream.

Comment: Sorry @Robert, the rates/example was a mistake as the rates object was too big I created the example in the same way but forgot to change it in the call. Regarding the JSON.enconde its use wasn't in the first code I pasted although it was something I tried, the update is the error I get trying to use it.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpClientRequest#id_write - You cannot directly pass the list to the write function. You have to explicitly convert it via JSON.encode. And on the receiver side you should the read the whole contents, convert the string to a object and call the function yourself.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Robert, got it after re-reading your previous comment. I was obsessed with the "receiving" part. The "update" code works just changing the post code to pass JSON.encode

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change `request.write(example);` to ` request.write(JSON.encode(example));`? The error comes from the message being just the `.toString()` result of the list, which does `.toString()` on the keys, not string escaping, so the strings values are not quoted as they should be in JSON.

Comment: Yes, @lrn. It went away. And thanks for your explanation of the reason not to be actually sent as JSON if not using JSON.encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `dart:convert` package.

You can then use:

`String str = JSON.encode(obj)`

and

`var obj = JSON.decode(str)`

to convert string/json.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I've updated the answer as that's why I'm trying to do with no luck